# Getting all selected toggle buttons from same group

Tags: java, javafx, toggle

I have 3 toggle buttons (FXML):

```
<ToggleButton fx:id="toggle1" text="Option 1" />
<ToggleButton fx:id="toggle2" text="Option 2" />
<ToggleButton fx:id="toggle3" text="Option 3" />
```

Those are several options the user can select or deselect. Multiple selection should also be possible.
In order to get all selected toggles, I put them into one toggle group:

```
final ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

toggle1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
toggle2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
toggle3.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```

But, in that case, only 1 button at a time can be selected, not 2 or 3.

How to get all selected toggle buttons from the same group?
So, basically, same principle as with check boxes.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the `ToggleGroup` purpose. If you want to be able to select at least 2 `ToggleButton`, it should **not** be in the same `ToggleGroup` (as described in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html), ToggelGroup's purpose is to manage the single selection Toggle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CheckBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html) and make it look like a radio button using CSS.
To get all selected checkboxes, you can create an observable collection like [ObservableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html) and assign listeners to the checkboxes, when a checkbox is selected add it to the collection and remove it when it gets unselected

```
ObservableSet<CheckBox> selectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableSet();
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
checkBox1.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, selectedNow) -> {
    if (selectedNow) {
        selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox1);
    } else {
        selectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox1);
    }
});
```